# Errors shown during runtime time uprgrade, are they normal?

Tags: runtime-upgrade, rococo, parachain-collator

I've just performed a runtime upgrade for a parachain running on rococo, and although the runtime upgrade succeeded in the end, the log seems to show that it the upgrade was run 3 times, and the first 2 failed with the following errors:

```
023-12-13 17:36:59 [Parachain] panicked at 'No new validation function found in storage, GoAhead signal is not expected', /home/sebastian/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/7c9fd83/cumulus/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:595:21
2023-12-13 17:36:59 [Parachain] 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.
2023-12-13 17:36:59 [Parachain] 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.
2023-12-13 17:36:59 [Parachain] ❗️ Inherent extrinsic returned unexpected error: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x4f3bd7 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0xc0d5 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha38e6eecb0b0460a
    2: 0x31417f - <unknown>!frame_support::storage::transactional::with_transaction::hc0ffff6346f7201f
    3: 0x41f4cd - <unknown>!<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Call<T> as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::{{closure}}::ha89f2c29bdc1e730
    4: 0x429ffd - <unknown>!environmental::local_key::LocalKey<T>::with::hc67cc26f8df15aab
    5: 0x432ee - <unknown>!<hashed_parachain_runtime::RuntimeCall as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::h7e7255660c638f09
    6: 0x4156b - <unknown>!<hashed_parachain_runtime::RuntimeCall as sp_runtime::traits::Dispatchable>::dispatch::hd4c057d0e587ce77
    7: 0x38ff71 - <unknown>!<sp_runtime::generic::checked_extrinsic::CheckedExtrinsic<AccountId,Call,Extra> as sp_runtime::traits::Applyable>::apply::hf257bbc56e628d94
    8: 0x350a04 - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::apply_extrinsic::he7d68a5fbe0504a2
    9: 0x3f2c7f - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_apply_extrinsic. Dropping.
2023-12-13 17:36:59 [Parachain] panicked at 'set_validation_data inherent needs to be present in every block!', /home/sebastian/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/7c9fd83/cumulus/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:268:18
2023-12-13 17:36:59 [Parachain] ✨ Imported #171167 (0x7577…b8ae)
```

Does anyone know what could be the cause? Is this normal? The upgraded parachain is producing blocks.

When running the upgrade locally, I never saw these errors.

Also, I'm not sure if it is related, but the parachain was showing (and is still showing after the upgrade) the following issue before performing the upgrade:
[Started getting: Aura pallet "Slot must increase" Error on running collator](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10613/started-getting-aura-pallet-slot-must-increase-error-on-running-collator)

Finally, after the runtime upgrade, every so often the collator is showing the following error:

```
2023-12-13 18:41:12 [Parachain]  Starting consensus session on top of parent 0x745f7b952b07895fc5cab314eadebe0f6d468853a0d3c725bfe4e204be7db3e3    
2023-12-13 18:41:12 [Parachain] panicked at 'no space left for the block in the unincluded segment', /home/sebastian/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/7c9fd83/cumulus/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:1350:9    
2023-12-13 18:41:12 [Parachain] 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.    
2023-12-13 18:41:12 [Parachain] 1 storage transactions are left open by the runtime. Those will be rolled back.    
2023-12-13 18:41:12 [Parachain] ❗️ Inherent extrinsic returned unexpected error: Error at calling runtime api: Execution failed: Execution aborted due to trap: wasm trap: wasm `unreachable` instruction executed
WASM backtrace:
error while executing at wasm backtrace:
    0: 0x4f3bd7 - <unknown>!rust_begin_unwind
    1: 0xc0d5 - <unknown>!core::panicking::panic_fmt::ha38e6eecb0b0460a
    2: 0x143df9 - <unknown>!cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::<impl cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Pallet<T>>::maybe_drop_included_ancestors::h2286e2e150ceb572
    3: 0x31395b - <unknown>!frame_support::storage::transactional::with_transaction::hc0ffff6346f7201f
    4: 0x41f4cd - <unknown>!<cumulus_pallet_parachain_system::pallet::Call<T> as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::{{closure}}::ha89f2c29bdc1e730
    5: 0x429ffd - <unknown>!environmental::local_key::LocalKey<T>::with::hc67cc26f8df15aab
    6: 0x432ee - <unknown>!<hashed_parachain_runtime::RuntimeCall as frame_support::traits::dispatch::UnfilteredDispatchable>::dispatch_bypass_filter::h7e7255660c638f09
    7: 0x4156b - <unknown>!<hashed_parachain_runtime::RuntimeCall as sp_runtime::traits::Dispatchable>::dispatch::hd4c057d0e587ce77
    8: 0x38ff71 - <unknown>!<sp_runtime::generic::checked_extrinsic::CheckedExtrinsic<AccountId,Call,Extra> as sp_runtime::traits::Applyable>::apply::hf257bbc56e628d94
    9: 0x350a04 - <unknown>!frame_executive::Executive<System,Block,Context,UnsignedValidator,AllPalletsWithSystem,COnRuntimeUpgrade>::apply_extrinsic::he7d68a5fbe0504a2
   10: 0x3f2c7f - <unknown>!BlockBuilder_apply_extrinsic. Dropping.    
2023-12-13 18:41:12 [Parachain] panicked at 'set_validation_data inherent needs to be present in every block!', /home/sebastian/.cargo/git/checkouts/polkadot-sdk-cff69157b985ed76/7c9fd83/cumulus/pallets/parachain-system/src/lib.rs:268:18
```

Does anyone know what could be causing it?